# UI-Grid pagination template editable

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

is there any way to edit pagination template from ui-grid

[image]

need to remove **blue color rounded** and replace selected row index value of total number row in that page

could any one please help out, Thanks in advance!!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use paginationTemplate option:

```
    self.gridOptions = {
        enablePaginationControls: true,
        paginationTemplate: $http.get('/Content/paging-control-template.html', { cache: $templateCache }).then(function (response) {
            return response.data;
        })}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use pagination controlled by API

http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/214_pagination

like this:

```
<div class="left" >
    <a ng-click="page >= 1 ? gridApi.pagination.seek(1): '' "><i class="material-icons left">skip_previous</i></a>
    <a ng-click="page >= 1 ? gridApi.pagination.previousPage() : '' "><i class="material-icons left">fast_rewind</i></a>
    {{page}} / {{pages}}
    <a ng-click="page < pages ? gridApi.pagination.nextPage() : '' "><i class="material-icons">fast_forward</i></a>
    <a ng-click="page < pages ? gridApi.pagination.seek(pages) : ''  "><i class="material-icons">skip_next</i></a>
</div>
```